# Android Tabhost Content freezes on Tablet but not in Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-tabhost, tablet

i have some strange things going on here!

i have a Tabhost, with 3 tabs. In my emulator, it´s working fine, going forth and back.
But on my Tablet(s) (HP Touchpad & Samsung Galaxy Tab 1) it isnt working. I go from Tab 1 to Tab 2, but can´t go back. When i go to Tab 3 the content freezes of tab3 and i cant go back to tab1 or tab2 (or ... at least the content doesn´t show what it shall show (and what it shows correctly in the emulator).

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
TabHost mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost); 

    Intent tab1 = new Intent(this, tab1.class);

    TabHost.TabSpec tab1Spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("tab1").setContent(tab1);
    mTabHost.addTab(tab1Spec);
// this 2 more times with my other tabs.
```

thx for your help! i dont know where i should look, if it does (somehow) the correct things :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use aLogcat (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) to see if you haven't received any errors. I would guess that you will see an error with something that has gone wrong, maybe device specific.

As far as I can tell from the code you have given, it looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent().setClass(this, YourClass.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

This was the line of code i was searching for. Somehow , because of this flag, it is working differently. But thank you very much anyways, for aLogCat. This will make some things much easier for me in the future!